# Connect to Googles Datastore with JWT and dart

Tags: dart, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use the auto-generated [dart_datastore_v1beta2_api_client](https://github.com/dart-google-apis/dart_datastore_v1beta2_api_client) library to connect to my Google Datastore in a server application I'm writing. I want to use [JWT](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) (obviously, since my server needs the rights to access my data without user interaction).

The dart_datastore_v1beta2_api_client uses [google_oauth2_client](https://github.com/dart-gde/dart-google-oauth2-library) and I haven't found a way to create do JWT authentication with it.

Is this simply not supported yet? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_web_token

```dart
import "package:google_analytics_v3_api/analytics_v3_api_console.dart";

Analytics analyticsClient = new Analytics(new oauth2.SimpleOAuth2Console(project, "", jwt.accessToken));
analyticsClient.makeAuthRequests = true;
```